# Wifi VLAN tagging through wifi extenders

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, vlan, asus, switching

This is my current setup: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/11t7j1u/new_home_network_layout_help_firewall_switch/

Where I have a switch that manages the VLANs, and after that, my main ASUS wifi router (RT-AC5300) and two ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) wifi extenders. Now, I want to differentiate by SSID which VLAN the devices should reside in. For example, the guest wifi devices should go into another VLAN than the main wifi SSID.

This means, I need to replace my main ASUS router, because it cannot associate SSIDs with VLANs. The model I checked out is the ASUS GT-AX6000 (which understands VLANs (https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1049415/)).

So my question is: If the AiMesh wifi extenders just extend the wifi signal, is the main router doing the VLAN tagging per SSID? Or do I need to replace the XT8 with the ZenWiFi Pro XT12?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLANs only exist on wired network, so tagging is always done where the traffic enters the wire. Over the air traffic is separated by the SSIDs. So the question becomes "are TX8 extenders compatible with GT-AX6000 router".

According to what I can find in ASUS pages, both AX6000 and XT8 support AiMesh. Based on that, no, you don't have to swap extenders.

Comment: That's great, thank you @Peregrino69 ! Great that I don't have to spend another 500 bucks :)